# Free Tier in Google Cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an account setup in Google Cloud platform. How do I know if I have set up a free tier account or upgraded account? I see this account a while back and I m not really sure what type of account I set it up.

I do see that i have $300 credits available. Does that mean that I m using free tier account?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. There is a little gift box on the top of the console that shows us if it is a free tier account and allows us to upgrade as well